# MySQL query, problem with my join?

Tags: mysql

I'am not sure that while problem, but take a look:

I have 3 tables:

1. Categories: id, icon, name;
2. Subcategories: id, name, description, category_id;
3. Topics: id, title, text, author, created, subcategory_id;

Now I'm trying get this info(query):

```
  $String = "SELECT
  categories.id AS catid,
  categories.icon AS caticon,
  categories.name AS catname,
  subcategories.id AS scatid,
  subcategories.name AS scatname,
  subcategories.description AS scatdescription,
  subcategories.category_id AS scatcatid,
  COUNT(topics.id) AS tid,
  topics.title AS ttitle,
  topics.author AS tauthor,
  topics.created AS tcreated
       FROM
  categories
LEFT JOIN
  subcategories
ON
  subcategories.category_id = 1
LEFT JOIN
  topics
ON
  subcategories.id = topics.subcategory_id
GROUP BY
 categories.id";
```

Result:

Categories from 5 showing 5 - OK,
  Subcategories from 4 showing only 1 in first categories.

Maybe the query is too long? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: on the first join, you have written: subcategories.category_id = 1 ... this, as I understood, will join on all subcategories of category 1 only ...

Answer (score 2):

this

```
LEFT JOIN
  subcategories
ON
  subcategories.category_id = 1
```

should be this

```
LEFT JOIN
  subcategories
ON
  subcategories.category_id = categories.id
```

Comment: Yes, get same result. only 1 subcategory in categories.

Comment: $string_result = mysql_query($string_query)or die(mysql_error());

while($string_row = mysql_fetch_array($string_result)){

Maybe here wrong ?

Comment: looks fine (except neither result nor row are strings, so if you want to put the type in the name, it's the wrong one. not related to functioning though in any way)

maybe try it a little easier first - what happens if you leave out the second join on the topics?